# objective-c super rich text field for a notebook application

Tags: objective-c, ipad, richtextbox, uitextfield, text-editor

I am trying to create a new iPad application which will be like a notebook.
I want to allow the user to edit the font, size, color, bold italic or underline
for any separate word in the field, or even edit some of the letters in a word.

is there any easy way to do it? or should i go the hard way and every word that its style was changed should go in another invisible uitextfield ?

please help me, i need this for school.
thank you!
Elad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to learn the Core Text api's

Maybe some of the source to the html -> core text control discussed at http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/ might be of some assistance.

There is also a good session on Core Text in the WWDC 2010 videos.